# Chaining task-based methods only if each task completes / validates successfully

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a chain of task-returning methods, all returning some `Task<SomeResponse<T>>`. `SomeResponse<T>` is a generic response class exposing properties like whether the response was successful (`IsSuccess`), if it's successful a `T Data` property containing the returning object, and if not an accompanying error message.

Let's assume I have 3 such methods (all of them returning `SomeResponse<T>`). I only want to keep executing the tasks one-by-one until one of them fails or all of them succeed. The flow would look like this:

```
var first = await firtTask(someParam);
if (!first.IsSuccess) return first;
var second = await secondTask(first.Data);
if (!second.IsSuccess) return second;
var third = await thirdTask(second.Data);
return third; // doesn't matter if it succeeded or not as it's the last one, no need to check.
```

My issue here is that the `SomeResponse<T>` of each call needs to be validated for success before proceeding to the next await, which adds a lot of repetitive validation code. Checking if each task completed successfully is not enough, as I then have to inspect it's `SomeResponse<T>.IsSuccess` property before proceeding to the next task.

I tried creating an extension method on top of `Task<SomeResponse<T>>` for this:

```
public static Task<SomeResponse<T>> OnSuccessChainAsync<T>(this Task<SomeResponse<T>> startingTask, Func<T, Task<SomeResponse<T>>> continuationTask)
{
    // omitting null checks etc

    var continuation = startingTask.ContinueWith(
        async previousTask =>
        {
            var response = await previousTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!response.IsSuccess)
            {
                return response;
            }

            return await continuationTask(response.Data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }, TaskScheduler.Current);

    return continuation.Unwrap();
}
```

This now allows me to write:

```
public override Task<SomeResponse<TValue>> AddAsync(TValue someValue)
{
    return firstTask(someValue)
           .OnSuccessChainAsync(secondTask)
           .OnSuccessChainAsync(thirdTask);
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm heading in the wrong direction here. I am mixing `async-await` with TPL's `ContinueWith`, and on top of that I get a [VSTHRD003 Avoid awaiting foreign Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md) from my analyzers.

Comment: It looks to me like you've re-invented exceptions, but worse. Using exceptions will do exactly what you want here: stop execution at the point that they occur, and it's impossible to forget to check whether one has occurred

Comment: @canton7 each of the task-based methods returning a `SomeResponse<T>` are calling an external project that might be throwing exceptions there. `SomeResponse<T>` informs that something happened on the other end (through `IsSuccess`) without throwing an exception (nothing went wrong on this side).

Comment: I know that's how things *are* -- I'm saying if you *change* that so that you throw an exception intead of using `Response<T>.IsSuccess`, you won't need all of this messy, error-prone overhead. Exceptions are useful, have their place, and are well-integrated into the language.

Comment: Hmm, trying to understand here: If I called an `GetCustomerByName(canton7)` API, and the API itself returned a `404` etc, why would I throw an `Exception` on my side?

Comment: Because that provides the behaviour you want, which is to stop executing the method you're currently executing, and return to the caller. It has the nice property that you can't forget to check whether the API returned 404 or not.

Comment: @globetrotter I've developed a library that I think fits your needs exactly (https://github.com/silkfire/Ultimately) which allows you to chain methods (also has full async support) and to short-circuit, returning immediately if a previous operation in a chain is unsuccessful.

Comment: @silkfire thanks, does this have documentation? I'm looking to see for examples to see whether this would fit my scenario.

Comment: @globetrotter There's more documentation in the base repo at https://github.com/nlkl/Optional, but the gist would be something like: `await firstTask(someParam).FlatMapAsync(r => secondTask(r.Data)).FlatMapAsync(r => thirdTask(r.Data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix the old-style `ContinueWith` with `async/await`.
In fact, try and avoid `ContinueWith` completely: it's horrendously complex with lots of bits of subtle behaviour, half of which you never want to think about and half of which are much more clearly expressed with `async/await`.

Why not simplify things a bit:

```
public static async Task<SomeResponse<T>> ExecuteInSequence<T>(
    T firstData,
    params Func<T, Task<Response<T>>>[] funcs)
{
    T data = firstData;
    foreach (var func in funcs)
    {
        var response = await func(data);
        if (!response.IsSuccess)
        {
            return response;
        }

        data = response.Data;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
ExecuteInSequence(someValue, task1, task2, task3);
```

There's no mixing of anything, no chaining, just a straightforward loop.

---

If you were going to write this as an extension method on `Task<SomeResponse<T>>`, I'd still keep everything as `await`s:

```
public static async Task<SomeResponse<T>> OnSuccessChainAsync<T>(
    this Task<SomeResponse<T>> startingTask,
    Func<T, Task<SomeResponse<T>>> continuationTask)
{
    // startingTask will probably have already completed (especially if
    // it's one which we created on a previous invocation), in which case
    // this await will be synchronous.

    var result = await startingTask;
    if (!result.IsSuccess)
    {
        return result;
    }

    return await continuationTask(result.Data);
}
```

Comment: Obviously much simpler than mine, many thanks! Where would this fit from a reusability standpoint? Should it be some helper, or part of `SomeResponse<T>`?

Comment: I wouldn't put it on `SomeResponse<T>`, so on some helper somewhere. Maybe in a dedicated helper, maybe simply on the (single) class which uses it.

Comment: @globetrotter I also wrote an await-only version of your continuation extension method

Comment: thanks! the await-only version returns the same warning as the one I originally had: VSTHRD003 Avoid awaiting foreign Tasks (not sure whether it's a valid warning or should be suppressed)

Comment: @globetrotter I'd call that a false positive and suppress it - you know where the Task came from, it's just the analyzer doesn't

Comment: Many thanks! All remarks and feedback in OP as well as this answer very useful.